# what does this weird function do?

Tags: bit-manipulation

what does this function do as I couldn't figure out the purpose of it.

```
int f( int n, int l, int r )  
{  
return (n << l) >> r;  
}
```

Comment: Hint: use unsigned types (or the result will be sign-extended)

Comment: The argument n should definitely be of an unsigned type to make the code more robust. The left shift of a signed quantity can overflow the signed integer range, leaving the result undefined per standard C/C++ semantics. Likewise, the right shift of a negative quantity provides an undefined result.

Answer (score 4):

It shifts n l bits to the left then r bits to the right

It effectively multiplies by 2^l and then divides by 2^r

Or put another way, it will zero out the low order (l-r) bits.

Comment: I knew the first two of them but not the third comment. I tried the code but wasn't exactly sure the purpose of the function. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I always approach these by doing an experiment with smaller numbers and thinking in binary.  E.g. let's make them **unsigned** 8-bit values first.  Let `n` be `0xFF (255)`, `l` be `3`, `r` be `2`.

So it's 2 steps (cha-cha).  First step we shift left `l` bits.

```
1111 1111b << 3 == 1111 1000b == 0xF8 == 248
```

Then we shift the result right `r` bits:

```
1111 1000b >> 2 == 0011 1110b == 0x3E == 62
```

Now as @wildplasser noted, your values are signed, so instead of shifting in 0's, you'll be sign-extended.  So let's assume 8-bit **signed** values.  Let `n` be `0xFF` again, `(-1)` in decimal.

The left shift remains the same, but when you right shift, the sign bit will be extended.

```
1111 1111b << 3 == 1111 1000b == 0xF8 == -8
1111 1000b >> 2 == 1111 1110b == 0xFE == -2
```

So I'm not sure what the *intention* of the function is, but at least I understand what it does.  If this is some standard idiom for doing something, I don't know what it is.

Comment: I thought of the same that the function was used for doing something of a standard idiom. Thanks for your comments.